# What mail service/server to use while in dev mode in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It does not seem that SendGrid has a free account that one could use to test in development mode. What are the current alternatives/best practices for this?

Comment: Why do you need a SMTP server?
In dev mode rails does not send emails but rather posts the resulting email header/body to the console where you can inspect it and check if it's what you want.. 
If you set it up to send emails, you usually don't need a SMTP server you own, rails will just connect to the target SMTP directly and deliver the message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good option is using the letter_opener gem.  See https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener

First add the gem to your development environment and run the bundle command to install it.

```
gem "letter_opener", :group => :development
```

Then set the delivery method in config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
```

Now any email will pop up in your browser instead of being sent. The messages are stored in tmp/letter_opener.